# How do i set the decimal values to be allowed?

Tags: vb.net

Basically I have a insert into the database where the values can be anything that's a decimal but I want to stop the user entering anything that doesn't end in a .50 or .00 ( e.g if Qtytxt1.text  =  "2.34" then error ) but if it is ending in .50 or .00 then it will allow my insert ( e.g if Qtytxt1.text = "2.50" then insert ) here is a codesnippet :

```
If Qtytxt1.Text <> "" And Qtytxt1.Text <> "0" And Count = 1 Then
                            command = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO GRN([POD Id], [Delivered     Qty], [Delivered Date], [Delivery No], [User]) " & _
                                              "VALUES ('" + PodId.Value + "','" + Qtytxt1.Text + "','" + ReceivedDate1.Text + "','" + DeliveryNo1.Text + "','" + Uname.ToString + "')", connection)
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
 End If
                    Else
                        Messagebox.Show("Cannot Save, Need To Fill The Received Date , Delivery No Or Qty exceedes the Bal...!")
                        Exit For
                    End If
crow = crow + 1
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Messagebox.Show("Error in Inserting the Value in GRN Table....!")
            Exit Sub
        Finally
            connection.Close()
        End Try
    Next
    If crow >= 1 Then
        Messagebox.Show("GRN has been updated successfully")
        save = True
    End If
```

So I know it should be something like :

```
 If Qtytxt1.Text <> "" And Qtytxt1.Text <> "0" And Count = 1 Then
 If Qtytxt1.Text Ends in .50 or .00 Then 
  Messagebox.Show("Please check Delivered Quantity ends in .50 or .00!") 
 Exit Sub
                        Else    command = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO GRN([POD Id], [Delivered     Qty], [Delivered Date], [Delivery No], [User]) " & _
                                              "VALUES ('" + PodId.Value + "','" + Qtytxt1.Text + "','" + ReceivedDate1.Text + "','" + DeliveryNo1.Text + "','" + Uname.ToString + "')", connection)
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
 End If
 End If
                    Else
                        Messagebox.Show("Cannot Save, Need To Fill The Received Date , Delivery No Or Qty exceedes the Bal...!")
                        Exit For
                    End If
crow = crow + 1
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Messagebox.Show("Error in Inserting the Value in GRN Table....!")
            Exit Sub
        Finally
            connection.Close()
        End Try
    Next
    If crow >= 1 Then
        Messagebox.Show("GRN has been updated successfully")
        save = True
    End If
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: you could use a `NumericUpDown` and an increment of `.5`; or you could round the textbox inputs for the user.

Comment: There is a `String.EndsWith` method that you can use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. But I'd recommend the NumericUpDown that's already been suggested.

Comment: value = math.floor(cint(qtytxt1.text) * 2) / 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I would put this in the textChanged event of your TextBox.  I am not sure if you are using a Submit button or something, but this just verifies that what is entered is numeric (i.e. only one decimal point, no alphas) and that it is divisible by .50.

```
If IsNumeric(Qtytxt1.text) AndAlso CDec(Qtytxt1.Text) Mod .50 = 0 Then
    Me.btnSubmit.Enabled = True
Else
    Me.btnSubmit.Enabled = False
End If
```

Also, you should look at SQL Injection vulnerabilities as SLaks suggested.  Using parameters would be better.